# PHP CURL SFTP Read File?

Tags: php, curl, sftp

I am trying to figure out how to read a file and get the contents from a remote SFTP connection via php/curl. I currently have the code below to read a list of files in a  directory.

```
$ch = curl_init('sftp://' . $sftpServer . ':' . $sftpPort . $sftpRemoteDir . '/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '*****:*****');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, '1L');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

if I change curl_init to the line below (file name added) how can I read  that file?

```
$ch = curl_init('sftp://' . $sftpServer . ':' . $sftpPort . $sftpRemoteDir . '/filename.txt');
```

Comment: I can’t help you with curl, but I can tell you that [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/) has support, and the code is way more portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$response` variable will contain the file data. If you want to save the file to your server's machine, you can write the contents of that file using `file_put_contents`.

```php
$ch = curl_init('sftp://' . $sftpServer . ':' . $sftpPort . $sftpRemoteDir . '/filename.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '*****:*****');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, '1L');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents("/path/to/save/filename.txt", $response);
```

If you want to read the plaintext (available for text files, including `.txt`s), then you should be able to simply read the `$response` variable, which should be a string.